# CodeIgniter Session Userdate seems not to exists

Tags: session, session-cookies, codeigniter-2

I'm coding my first CI project and try to write a loginscript. Everything works almost fine, except that the session userdata is not available (even not if i check my cookies / sessions in Firefox).

I don't understand why the session userdata only are available after login, but if i load the same page again (not a refresh, but a new load) i would expect i still will be logged in, but i'm logged out ? Even if i try to read the session userdata it doesn't exists.

I simplified my script to an example version for stackoverflow. Who can tell me how this session issue can be solved?

Regards,
Guido

```
<?php
class Test extends CI_Controller
{   

    function index()
    {
        $logged_in = $this->is_logged_in();
        if($logged_in) { 
            echo "You are logged in. <a href='test/logout'>Logout</a> | <a href='../'>Return to index</a>"; 
        }
        else { 
            echo "You are logged out";
            echo form_open('test/check_login');
            echo "Email: ".form_input('email', set_value('email'));
            echo "Password: ".form_password('password', set_value('password'));
            echo form_submit('submit','Login');
            echo form_close();
        }
    }

    function is_logged_in() // check if user has logged in
    {
        // AUTOLOAD SESSIONS HAS SET in autoload.php-config >> $autoload['libraries'] = arra y('database', 'session', 'email');
        $is_logged_in = $this->session->userdata('is_logged_in');       
        if($is_logged_in) { 
            return TRUE; 
        }
        else { 
            return FALSE; 
        }
    }

    function check_login()
    {
        $client_id = $this->validate();
        if(is_numeric($client_id)) // if the user's credentials validated then user exists
        {
            $data = array(
                'client_id' => $client_id,
                'is_logged_in' => true
            );
            $this->session->set_userdata($data);
        }       
        $this->index();
    }

    // normally we put this function in a model, but for this example we put it here.
    function validate() // check if user exists in database
    {
        $this->db->where('email', $this->input->post('email'));
        $this->db->where('password', md5($this->input->post('password')));
        $query = $this->db->get('client_users'); // this is our user table

        if($query->num_rows == 1) // user exists
        {
            $row = $query->row();
            return $row->id_client;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    function logout()
    {
        $this->session->sess_destroy(); // kill session, so user will be logged out.
        redirect('/test');
    }

}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your validate function's if statement should read:

```
if($query->num_rows() == 1) // user exists
```

You left out the () after num_rows.

Edit: After further review, that shouldn't matter. The only other thing I can tell is maybe your result is not equal to 1. Either the user isn't found or you're getting more than one result, both resulting in !== 1.

Comment: Well, it seems something is wrong using 'session' on my localhost... but i don't know where the problem starts.

Comment: I have solved the issue... It's a 'localhost thing.. Since i was testing on localhost it seems the domain-setting for CI must be empty. (See http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/209191/ )